# Opencl independent queues and clFinish within openmp sections

Tags: c++, opencl, openmp

Im making an opencl wrapper that uses a different command queue for each buffer.

All read/write oprations are non-blocking.

**The problem is, one of the read/write operations is not issued(as it seems from profiler). CodeXL profiler shows holes. I marked them on the picture.**

[image]

**Question: What can cause this problem? I check cl errors but all give CL_SUCCESS.**

The flow of c++ opencl 1.2 program:

```
  (from main thread)
   issue write buffer 0
   issue write buffer 1
   issue write buffer N

   (from many threads by openmp body)
   clFinish(queue0)
   clFinish(queue1)
   clFinish(queue2)

   (from main thread)
   issue kernel 0
   issue kernel 1
   issue kernel N
   clFinish(kernelQueue)

  (from main thread)
   issue read buffer 0
   issue read buffer 1
   issue read buffer N

   (from many threads by openmp body)
   clFinish(queue0)
   clFinish(queue1)
   clFinish(queue2) ----> has some holes!!!
   clFinish(queueN)
```

Here is how main thread looks:

```
void Air::update_air_and_h_gpu(void)
{
    if (airMode != 4) 
    {




            /*  update air*/

        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("pv",&pv[0][0]);    
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("vx",&vx[0][0]);    
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("vy",&vy[0][0]);    
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("fvx",&fvx[0][0]);  
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("fvy",&fvy[0][0]);      
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("bmap_blockair",&bmap_blockair[0][0]);  
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("bmap",&bmap[0][0]);    
        gpu->WriteToClFromCPP("kernelArr",&kernel[0]);


            /* update heat*/    
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("hv",&hv[0][0]);    
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("ambientAirTemp",&(ambientAirTemp));    
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("gravityMode",&(sim.gravityMode));  
        gpu->WriteToClFrom2DCPP("bmap_blockairh",&bmap_blockairh[0][0]);


        gpu->syncW();

        /* update air*/
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirReduceEdge0");
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirReduceEdge1");
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirClearVelWall");
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirPressAdjVel");
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirVelAdjPress");
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirBigLoop");
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirBigLoop2");

        /* update heat*/
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirHeatLoop0");
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirHeatLoop1");
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirHeatLastLoop");
        gpu->Compute("UpdateAirHeatLastLoop2");

        gpu->sync();

        /*update air*/
        gpu->ReadFromClTo2DCPP("pv",&pv[0][0]);
        gpu->ReadFromClTo2DCPP("vx",&vx[0][0]);
        gpu->ReadFromClTo2DCPP("vy",&vy[0][0]);

        /* update heat*/
        gpu->ReadFromClTo2DCPP("hv",&hv[0][0]);


        gpu->syncR();



    }

}
```

Here is how gpu->syncR() and gpu->syncW are done through openmp(activated in options too):

```
void syncR()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(2);  //tried 8 but holes still exist
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<cqR.size();i++)
    {
        cqR[i].finish();
    }
}

void syncW()
{
    omp_set_num_threads(2); //tried 8 but holes still exist
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0;i<cqW.size();i++)
    {

        cqW[i].finish();
    }
}
```

Here is a closer look:

See the blue bars on the right side, one of them is missing some times.
[image]

Device: HD7870
Host: FX8150

Opencl 1.2 C++ bindings.

Comment: While I think what you're doing ought to work, it's not obvious what advantage you might gain. Your program's time will be dominated by the  time to compute the OpenCL kernel and by the latency of the PCIe bus. Using multiple threads on the host CPU won't make your PCIe bus any faster or wider, and a single core is more than capable of saturating the bus on its own.

Comment: Actually, using multiple threads to access the same GPU can incur additional overhead so you don't want to do this.  Regarding the missing data transfer, do you see the same behaviour if you remove OpenMP?

Comment: Same behaviour(or observation) happens without openmp(all serial main thread) too! Maybe codexl is not mature enough yet? Even AMD's own examples such as "bufferBandwidth" gives many leak warnings too. I think I will try clEnqueueMapBuffer to use DMA to get 6GB/s instead of 1.4GB/s as in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using separate command queue for every mem object IMHO looks like not best practice. In such case you are issuing commands seldom in scope of every queue. Commands can't be reordered, put in conveyor, etc. Briefly - you can't benefit massive data transfers & you're wasting your CPU resources on multiple queues handling. My advice is to use several command queues with OpenMP thread-safe access:

```
cl_command_queue 
    q_DtoH = clCreateCommandQueue(...),
    q_DtoD = clCreateCommandQueue(...)
    ...;

#pragma omp parallel for
for(;;)
{
    #pragma omp critical
    clEnqueueNDWriteBuffer(q_DtoH, ...); //Or whatever else

    ....
}
```

Ideally, try to use out-of-order queues with events synchronization for data transfers. Also, objects reference counts are handy for debugging purposes (Presumably, your command queues are using same context, you may check it's ref counts).

And, in your code snippet:

```
/* update heat*/
....
gpu->Compute("UpdateAirHeatLoop0");
gpu->sync();

/*update air*/
gpu->ReadFromClTo2DCPP("pv",&pv[0][0]);
...
```

Why not use same command queue to issue kernel execution & data transfer? This will allow you to get rid of sync points.

Comment: Thank you, I also learned something by trial&error: maximum commandqueue number is 48 for my system. A single out-of-order queue should do the trick(drivers auto-optimize it maybe? like reordering accesses so they become more efficient)

Comment: Also just found out that not all platforms have out-of-order capabilities.